# Helper functions for use with std::variant without an actual object

Tags: c++, abstract-factory, variant-type

Sometimes, you want to an type of a particular index in an std::variant, and do something with that type without having an actual object. An example use-case would be de-serialization. What do you think of the following approach?

```
    /**
     * @brief Used as placeholder to allow tag dispatching
     */
    template<class T>
    using empty = std::type_identity<T>;

    /**
     * @brief Find the index of the type that satisfies pred
     */
    template<class Variant, class Predicate, size_t N = std::variant_size_v<Variant>>
    constexpr size_t find_type(Predicate&& pred)
    {
        if constexpr(N != 0)
        {
            using current_type = std::variant_alternative_t<N - 1, Variant>;
            if(pred(empty<current_type>{}))
            {
                return N - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return find_type<Variant, N - 1, Predicate>(std::forward<Predicate>(pred));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return std::variant_npos;
        }
    }

    template<class Callback, class ... Args>
    using callback_wrapper = void (*)(Callback&&, Args&&...);

    template<class Variant, size_t N, class Callback, class ... Args>
    constexpr void assign_callback(
        std::array<callback_wrapper<Callback, Args...>, std::variant_size_v<Variant>>& values)
    {
        if constexpr(N != 0)
        {
            using current_type = std::variant_alternative_t<N - 1, Variant>;
            values[N - 1] = [](Callback&& cb, Args&&... args){
                std::move(cb)(empty<current_type>{}, std::move(args)...);
            };
            assign_callback<Variant, N - 1>(values);
        }
    }

    template<class Variant, class Callback, class ... Args>
    constexpr auto create_vtable()
    {
        constexpr auto N = std::variant_size_v<Variant>;
        std::array<callback_wrapper<Callback, Args ...>, N> ret{};
        assign_callback<Variant, std::size(ret)>(ret);
        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * @brief Calls cb for an "empty" of type with index
     */
    template<class Variant, class Callback, class ... Args>
    decltype(auto) on_type_index(size_t index, Callback&& cb, Args&&... args)
    {
        static constexpr auto vtable = create_vtable<Variant, Callback, Args...>();
        vtable[index](std::forward<Callback>(cb), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sometimes, you want to an type of a particular index in an std::variant,

Yes, you can do that with [`std::variant_alternative_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant_alternative), which you are already using in your code.

> and do something with that type without having an actual object.

You can do lots of things with just types, but I think you mean you actually want to pass that type as a *function parameter* to another function. This is where you use `std::type_identity`; it provides you with an otherwise empty object but it has an associated type alias `type`.

I was thinking you might avoid having to use `std::type_identity` by allowing `Predicate` to be a template template parameter, then you can write:

```
template<class Variant, template<class> class Predicate, size_t N = std::variant_size_v<Variant>>
constexpr size_t find_type()
{
   ...
   if(Predicate<current_type>)
   ...
};
```

However, template template parameters can only be template classes, not template (`constepxr`) variables, and recursively calling `find_type()` with a template type is apparently impossible.

There are also some situations where [`std::declval()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) might be of use, although I don't think it would help you.

## Iterating over variants

You are using recursive functions to iterate over the possible variants. That is one way to do it. Another way is to use `std::apply()` in some way. Consider creating a helper function that creates a `std::tuple` of `empty` types for each of the variant's types:

```
template<class Variant, size_t... Is>
auto empties(std::index_sequence<Is...> = std::make_index_sequence<std::variant_size_v<Variant>>()) {
    return std::tuple<empty<std::variant_alternative_t<Is, Variant>>...>{};
}
```

Then you can pass it a lambda that iterates over each "`empty`" using a fold expression:

```
std::apply([](auto... types){
    (some_func(types), ...);
}, empties<Variant>());
```

Although it doesn't look any better than your approach. However, one advantage is that it iterates over the variant's types forward, instead of your recursive functions that go backwards, which might be surprising.

## Bug in `find_type()`

When you call `find_type()` recursively, you have the order of the template arguments wrong.

## Don't `std::move()` the callback and its arguments

You should not use `std::move()` when calling the callback. Instead, `std::forward()` the arguments and the callback, and use [`std::invoke()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) to call it:

```
values[N - 1] = [](Callback&& cb, Args&&... args) {
    std::invoke(std::forward<Callback>(cb), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};
```

Let the callback itself `std::move()` if so desired.

Comment: I thought std::forward only worked on function templates, and  this lambda is not a generic lambda.